# What type of event handler would I use to manipulate the size of a div?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, eventhandler

I have figured out how to use event handlers to manipulate color using `onmouseover` but I don't know what I would change here in order for it to affect the size of the divs.

What I basically have is 5 divs that are all green and 100x100 px. And I am trying to manipulate my event handlers to make any div that is moused over grow to 150x150.

This is what I have so far but I don't know what to change `this.style.backgroundColor` to.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="category">

<div class="content">
    <h2>title here</h2>
    <p>content area</p>
</div>

<div class="content">
    <h2>title here</h2>
    <p>content area</p>
</div>

<div class="content">
    <h2>title here</h2>
    <p>content area</p>
</div>

<div class="content">
    <h2>title here</h2>
    <p>content area</p>
</div>

<div class="content">
    <h2>title here</h2>
    <p>content area</p>
 </div>

</div>

<style>
div {background-color: springgreen;}
div {width: 100px;}
div {height: 100px;}
</style>

</body>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
</html>
```

and JavaScript

```
/**
* Created by Mark on 3/28/2015.
* 
*/

var category = document.getElementById("category");
for (var child = category.firstChild; child != null; child =               child.nextSibling) {
if (child.nodeType == 1 && child.className == "content") {
    child.onmouseover = function() {
        this.style.backgroundColor = "#FF0000";
    };

    child.onmouseout = function() {
        //let the original background show through.
        this.style.backgroundColor = "transparent";
    }


}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a custom event for that. If you really want an event. or else you can have a simple callback function.

```
var elem = $(".content-area");
// $ is document.querSeletor() not jQuery
EventTarget.call(elem);
```

So your actuall function should look like:

```
function resized(elem, cb) {
   var eW = elem.offsetWidth,
       eH = elem.offsetHeight;
   setInterval(function() {
     if(elem.width != eW || elem.height != eH) {
        eW = elem.width; eH = elem.height;
      // either cb() or elem.fire();
     }
   }, 2000)
 }
```

more or less, untested..